# Custom serialize_handler for custom php SessionHandler (DB storage)

Tags: php, session, serialization

In the process of using 3rd party (django) session management within php, i need to have **custom serialization functions** in order to encode/decode it properly to fit django's salted storage of session data. Currently, it appears that the ini setting session.serialize_handler can either be php or wddx.

Is there any way to set up a custom serialize_handler as a class?

I'd like to have something like this:

```
class CustomSessionSerializer {

    public static function serialize($data){
    // Serializes raw data
    }

    public static function unserialize($sdata){
    // Deserializes serialized data
    }
}
```

and have it used by my custom SessionHandler.

[`igbinary` project on github](https://github.com/igbinary/igbinary) seems to add a custom serialize_handler as a php extension. **I'm curious if custom serialization could not happen in another place than as a C extension.**

Comment: igbinary project on github (https://github.com/igbinary/igbinary) seems to achieve custom serialization but this goes far beyond what I've expected from php customization.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do it in plain PHP, unless you take over the entire `$_SESSION` superglobal and write everything session-related yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I've been dealing with this problem, and there is a solution for this.

The idea is that although you can easily modify the `session.serializer_handler` from PHP, you can empty the contents of `$ _SESSION` before running the serializer.
Using a class for the administration of session (like *Zend\Session\SessionManager*) in which is registered with `register_shutdown_function` a function, in which is passed back to `save_handler` a copy of `$ _SESSION` content and then `$ _SESSION` is empty.

So that the serializer runs but on empty string, and the custom serialization is executed on your custom `save_handler`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [session_set_save_handler()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) to use your own session handling functions

In PHP 5.4 you can use [SessionHandlerInterface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php).

By default you will receive already serialized data, so you will have to unserialize it and use your own serialization routines.

Comment: Crack, if you take a closer look to my question, you'll see that I've already set up a custom session handler. The question is about custom serialization since this step happens just before read, and just after write.

Comment: You are left with what session.serialize_handler lets you do (plain or with PHP extensions), or with using `read` and `write` handlers and doing custom unserialization -> PHP serialization / PHP unserialization -> custom serialization in them.

Answer (score 0):

Might look like a work-around but it does what you need. The serialization applies when your custom session handler receives the `$_SESSION` superglobal and you need to return it from the read handler as serialized. But, you can store the session as any serialization or format or anything you want.

Example

```
class SessionHandler {

    public function __construct() {
       session_set_save_handler(
            array($this, 'open')
           ,array($this, 'close')
           ,array($this, 'read')
           ,array($this, 'write')
           ,array($this, 'destroy')
           ,array($this, 'gc')
        );
    }

    public function open($savePath, $sessionName) {
        return true;
    }

    public function close() {
        return true;
    }

    public function read($id) {
        $data = CustomStorage::fetchSessionData($id);
        return serialize(
            CustomSerialization::unserialize($data);
        );
    }

    public function write($id, $serializedData) {
        CustomStorage::writeSessionData(
             $id
            ,CustomSerialization::serialize(unserialize($serializedData))
        );
        return true;
    }

    //gc and destroy
}
```

Although not pretty and with a bit of overhead, but you only need to control the serialization when storing, so it should do the trick.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks capi, unfortunately, it looks like the weird serialization happens when session_encode is called, and it doesn't appear to me that this step can be cancelled